# NSStringFromClass() exc_bad_access crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, class, nskeyedarchiver

I'm experiencing this crash in my application and I can't seem to figure out what is going wrong.

I've got an object with a property that holds on to a Class struct. I declare it like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) Class myClass;
```

Now, I'd like to serialize this object, so implemented NSCoding. That looks like this:

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
{
    self = [super init];
    self.myClass = NSClassFromString([coder decodeObjectForKey:@"myClass"]);
    self.title = [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"title"];
    return self;
}

- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
{
    [coder encodeObject:NSStringFromClass(self.myClass) forKey:@"myClass"];
    [coder encodeObject:self.title forKey:@"title"];
}
```

However, when I execute this line

```
    [coder encodeObject:NSStringFromClass(self.myClass) forKey:@"myClass"];
```

I get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS crash and I am struggling to find out why. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Try logging `self.controllerClass`. What is it?

Comment: Why is the property "assign" and not "strong" ? And try to proceed in steps: NSString * myClassString = NSStringFromClass(...) ; [coder encodeObject: myClassString ...]... Is there anything that jumps at you now?

Comment: Please check the retain count of myClass using Instruments. If you change myClass from assing to retain that will fix the problem (alredy mentioed by @verec).

Comment: @H2CO3 logging gives me a crash.

Comment: retaining worked... i mistakenly thought I was using ARC in this particular library

Comment: @verec: Class objects should live forever. Retaining and releasing class objects should have no effect.

Comment: @AmitVyawahare: Why? Class objects should not be deallocatable.